# detach inline js in drupal 7

Tags: javascript, module, drupal-7

In a module in drupal 7 a js is attached inline with the command
`$element['#attached']['js']`. I would like to ask whether there is a 'detach' command in order to remove this js in a later stage. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [hook_js_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7.x) in your theme's **template.php** file. Even if the javascript file is loaded inline it should appear in the hook's **$javascript** parameter.

Inside the hook's body you can just unset the javascript using unset(). Like so:

```
function MYTHEME_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  if ($some_condition) {
    unset($javascript['path/to/script.js']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! this also should work in case the .js is being loaded inside a module?

Comment: Yes, it should!

It is a little trick that the hooks that are written in the theme's **template.php** file are run last.

For example if you have hook_js_alter implemented in many modules on your Drupal website, the hook that is in template.php will run last, so this is the last place where you could modify javascript files.